# NullReferenceException when triggering an event

Tags: c#, .net, events, nullreferenceexception

i have this code I'm playing around with, but it causes a, for me at least, weird exception.

```
public class Flight
{
    public class MessageEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        public string msgContent;
    }

    public event System.EventHandler LogMessage;

    public void StartFlight()
    {
        string tmpDeparture = this.Departure;
        string tmpDestination = this.Destination;
        this.OnLogUpdate("Taking off from " + tmpDeparture + " now.");
        this.Destination = tmpDeparture;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.OnLogUpdate("Arriving in " + tmpDestination + " now.");
        this.Departure = tmpDestination;
    }

    protected virtual void OnLogUpdate(string logMessage)
    {
        MessageEventArgs e = new MessageEventArgs();
        if (logMessage == "")
            return;
        e.msgContent = logMessage;
        LogMessage(this, e);
    }
}
```

It causes a NullReferenceException at the,
     LogMessage(this, e);

I don't understand why it causes said exception when i have a practically identical setup in another class that works fine.
Also, when checking with the variable inspector, both `this` and `e` is set, and therefor not Null.

I'm still a somewhat new to C#, and especially events and delegates, so i have probably missed something more or less obvious

[Edit]

If it is because the event have no subscriptions, what is wrong with this?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Airport airport = new Airport();
    Flight flight = new Flight();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeEvents();
    }
    private void InitializeEvents()
    {
        this.airport.ErrorMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnErrorReceived);
        this.flight.LogMessage += new System.EventHandler(OnLogReceived);
    }
```

the subscription for the airport error message is working fine, but the one for the flight LogMessage doesn't?

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a minimal code set? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Done, removed most of the irrelevant code ( irrelevant to this problem at least )

Comment: 'LogMessage' is an event. If nobody susbcribes to the event, it will be null.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I already looked through that, and its not that i don't know what causes a NullReferenceException in general, but this case is different, i think...

Comment: This case is identical, and I believe there's an example in the linked question: nobody has subscribed to the event, so it's `null`. Check for null and set a breakpoint when it's null. You'll be able to see why it's `null`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the thing is, that it is subscribed, just like another almost identical working event is

Comment: It's not subscribed by the time you try to invoke it. Add a null check and I bet your problem goes away. Or set a breakpoint and see if it's null again by the time you invoke.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that much makes sense, and i have done both, and yes a null check does avoid the exception, but it doesn't fix the actual problem. Guess i should rephrase, or rephrase and re-ask the question? since the problem is, that it "is" subscribed ( well, apart from it apparently not being subscribed...)

Answer (score 2):

LogMessage is an event and not subscribed by other class. you should check if it's null before you trigger it

```
if (LogMessage != null)
{
    LogMessage(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that fixed the exception, thanks! Although i dont understand why it isn't subscribed properly

Comment: Event is reference type,if you donot set value to it,it's null.You should subscribe it in other class like this:
Flight flight=new Flight()
flight.LogMessage+=Func;
This will set value to LogMessage.and it's not null after assignment

Comment: this is not thread safe

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to add this line to your `Flight` object constructor

```
LogMessage += (s, o) => {};
```

this will add a dummy handler to your event and you can use it without checking for it's nullability every time but it has high overhead and if somebody set `LogMessage` to null then boom! `NullPointerException`.

another option is to check for nullability every time you want to fire your event

```
if(LogMessage != null)
{
   LogMessage(this, e);
}
```

but this can make race conditions in multi-thread scenarios when thread A check if `LogMessage` is null and it is not null and thread B set `LogMessage` to null and then thread A fires the `LogMessage` and boom! `NullPointerException`

the best way is to do it like this

```
protected virtual void OnLogUpdate(string logMessage)
{
    if (logMessage == "")
        return;

    MessageEventArgs e = new MessageEventArgs();
    var handler = LogMessage;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        e.msgContent = logMessage;
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and yea it all makes sense this way, except for the cause of it being null, i still don't understand that, as i have it subscribed like i have with a similar event from another class.

Comment: maybe `StartFlight()` is called before `InitializeEvents`

Comment: StartFlight() is called on a button press, where InitializeEvents are called at the same time the Form loads up. I have a almost identical button for the Airport ErrorMessage which works fine

Comment: you should track `OnLogUpdate` calls in your code, I think somewhere `OnLogUpdate` is called before `InitializeEvents `

Comment: When i set a breakpoint on InitializeEvents it pauses as soon as i run a debug session, since it does the initializing there. and When i have a breakpoint on OnLogUpdate, it first pauses when i press the button that i use to trigger the method, at which point it still consider the LogMessage to be Null

Comment: can you upload your code somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66530/discussion-between-ronin-and-dotctor).